# Why is $|\varphi(t)|$ not necessarily a characteristic function?

Tags: characteristic-functions

I came across the following statement in a book:

> If $\varphi(t)$ is a characteristic function, then $|\varphi(t)|$ is not necessarily a characteristic function.

Here's my argument:

By [Bochner’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)), we can check $|\varphi(t)|$ satisfies the three conditions:

- continuous at $t=0$
- $|\varphi(0)|=1$
- positive definite
  \begin{align}
  \sum_{i,j}\xi_i\bar\xi_j|\varphi(t_i-t_j)| &=\sum_{i,j}\xi_i\bar\xi_j|\varphi(t_i)||\varphi(t_j)| \\
  &=\left(\sum_i \xi_i|\varphi(t_i)|\right)\overline{\left(\sum_i \xi_i|\varphi(t_i)|\right)}\\
  &=\left|\sum_i \xi_i|\varphi(t_i)|\right|^2\geq 0
  \end{align}
  The equality holds only when $\xi_i=0,i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

What's the problem with this argument?

Comment: Define characteristic function

Comment: @zhw. A characteristic function of a random variable $X$ is $\varphi(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{itX})$

Comment: Why is continuous at t=0? What if 0 is a critical point of Phi?

Comment: @vvnitram this is a proposition of characteristic function. Now that phi is continous at 0， so is |phi|

Comment: @K.L. why? Im(Phi) is a subset of C, but im(|Phi|) is a subset of R

Comment: @vvnitram but it seems not to be a problem. By the triangular inequality in complex analysis, we have $||\varphi(t_i)|-|\varphi(t_j)||\leq |\varphi(t_i)-\varphi(t_j)|$. That indicates $\varphi$ continous at 0 => $|\varphi|$ continous at 0

Comment: Could you elaborate why the first "=" holds true? In general, $|\varphi(t_i-t_j)| \neq |\varphi(t_i)| \, |\varphi(t_j)|$, right?